# How do I get status of contactors using Arduino (more than 50 contactors)

Tags: arduino-uno, relay, shift-register

I am new to Arduino. Sorry if my question sounds wrong.

Interest areas: Multiple devices inter-connected on the cloud.
Single GSM for equipment in a typical panel connectivity for non-electrical parameter sensing devices e.g. Temperature, humidity.
Mechanical operations & connection status
Parameters of individual devices [non-communication capable]
Connectivity with cloud

Interest areas: Connectivity for electromechanical devices – Contactors, MCBs, RCCB etc
Parameters possible on IOT
Device Status possible on IOT
Size [Compactness] of the IOT solution to be integrated
Aux Power requirement & possible ways to provide the same
Memory retention 
Remote access/control and driving of the devices
The estimated cost of the IoT connectivity devices should be a fraction of the device cost [e.g. Contactor of 9A].
Voltage level high

I am trying to read the status of more than 50 contactors i.e whether they are in ON\OFF\trip state using Arduino and display it on screen.

Can I use a single microcontroller to read the status of 50 or more contactors?

I searched on the net and I found out it can be done using shift registers or a latching system, but I didn't understand the method at all.

Please, can anyone explain me the method of doing this?Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73040/discussion-on-question-by-r-zeiwald-how-do-i-get-status-of-contactors-using-ardu).

Answer (score 1):

Due to lack of specifics, I cannot be more precise with my answer, but since you are working with "high" voltage (I'll assume 220V/415V) I would suggest the best solution to monitoring the current will be current transformers.

These are non-intrusive devices that you pass a single conductor through. It generates a small current in proportion to a large current flowing through the conductor.

This small current is then converted into a small voltage by passing it through a resistor and then measuring the voltage across that resistor.

Since it is AC you are dealing with simple digital IO pins will not suffice (except see below) - no matter how many you have. You need analog inputs, and you need to be able to sample that analog signal fast enough to at least capture the peaks and troughs of the incoming waveform. That means sampling at many times the frequency of the supply. For 50Hz you want to sample either at, say, 500 sps or more, or to sample at a rate that isn't a multiple of, or factor of, 50, but for a longer period of time.

Interfacing an AC voltage like this involves adding an offset voltage to it so that the zero point of the AC voltage lies in the middle of the ADC's range. This is most often done by feeding a voltage of 50% Vcc into the current transformer as a "virtual ground", so all output from it is superimposed on this offset voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWpG6M.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Once you know the peak to peak voltage across the load resistor of the current transformer you can use that to calculate the peak to peak current the current transformer generated (Ohm's law), and thus the current through the central conductor.

This not only gives you the actual current through the conductor, but by simple logical reasoning, also gives you the state of the contactor: no current = contactor is off.

To reduce programming complexity at the cost of increased BOM cost it could be possible to build a simple rectifying and smoothing circuit (i.e., a simple integrating circuit) from diodes and a capacitor (either a single diode and a capacitor as a half-wave rectifier and smoothing, or a full-wave rectifier and smoothing) which will give you a simple DC voltage proportional to the current. Don't forget to take into account the voltage drop of the diode (or diodes) when doing your calculations, of course.

The integrating circuit could also be used, if you don't care about the current, to directly drive a digital input, as long as the voltage generated under normal load is above the threshold (V<sub>IH</sub>) of the IO pin, and never exceeds the maximum input voltage for the pin (a little over 5V).  Adding a 5.1V zener diode and series resistor can help protect the input. The same should be done to an analog input as well to protect it from overvoltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fU5sUk.png)</sup>

One important thing with this integrating circuit, though, is that any downward changes in the current will take time to be reflected in the output. That is caused by the time C1 takes to discharge down to the new voltage level through R1. Balancing these values so you get a reasonable amount of responsiveness yet minimum amount of ripple on the signal will take a little experimentation and calculation.

You can read more about current transformers and interfacing them to an Arduino [here](https://openenergymonitor.org/forum-archive/node/156.html).

---

For interfacing so many sensors to an Arduino you can, depending on if you are wanting to measure the current directly, or integrate the current to a DC voltage and use it as a threshold to a GPIO pin:

- Use shift registers (Parallel-to-Serial) for digital threshold reading,
- Use IO expanders (eg MCP23017) for digital threshold reading,
- Use external ADC chips (eg MCP3208) to provide more ADC inputs, or
- Use analog multiplexers (eg CD4051) to switch different analog voltages to a limited number of ADC inputs

Another option is to break your system down into smaller, more manageable, chunks.  Group your signals into small subsections and have each subsection handled by a separate controller - be that an Arduino (maybe a Mini, or a Micro, or something) to handle a small group of signals. These can then feed their data into a more powerful management system (maybe a Raspberry Pi) through a serial protocol of some form (or wirelessly if you want to spend extra money), which then forwards the readings on to your chosen web service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

There are special ICs, called Shift-In registers to do this job. You can daisy chain 4 of them, each capable of handling 8 outputs or inputs.

The most known is for outputs (e.g. LEDs) which is a 74HC595 (called shift-out register).

For inputs. you can use a CD4021BE. See the [Shiftin Example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ShiftIn) how to use them. 
It will cost 3 pins (except VCC/GND) to control 32 inputs, so you need 6 pins for 50 (max 64). You need 50 / 8 = 7 of these ICs, but they are very cheap (10 for about 2 dollars).

Note that you will receive either a 0 or 1, so it's up to you how to detect trip states.

Comment: Thanks! can I also read current or voltage using shift register plus some more circuitry?

Comment: No, you only get digital signals (0 or 1). I'm not aware of voltage (analog) readings... in that case you might need ADC converters probably. The Uno has 5, if you need more, you need a chip that has multiple ADC channels, but I don't have experience with that.